# Windows batch command to remove last line from a csv file created from sqlplus spooling

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, sqlplus, spool

I am creating a csv file from Oracle db using sqlplus spooling. The last line of the csv file contains spool summary of how many rows are selected, for e.g for a csv with 1641 rows in it (including header) the last line says

```
1641 rows selected.
```

I want to remove this line from the csv. Not sure if this can be achieved as a sqlplus parameter or by a windows batch script.

Appreciate any inputs to help me remove this last line (or not to create it at all) from the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in sql plus you would need to set feedback off

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the quick response. This is working as what I wanted..Thanks again!!